# Adding Custom Taxonomy to WordPress default Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to add custom taxonomy (tags) to WordPress default post type. because I wanna use that taxonomy for custom post type as well.

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function tag_synchro() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'QA Tags', 'Taxonomy General Name', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'QA Tag', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'QA Tags', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Tags', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tags Name', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New tag', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit tag', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update tag', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used tagd', ET_DOMAIN ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', ET_DOMAIN ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'update_count_callback'      => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => ae_get_option('tag_slug', 'qa-tag') ),
    );
register_taxonomy( 'qa_tag', array( 'post' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'tag_synchro', 0 );
```

I used above code, and it's seems not working. is there any way I can accomplish this work. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'init', 'tag_synchro', 10 );
```

It might be the case that, when you set priority to 0 , your callback does not get called.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to register a taxonomy is to wait for the action `registered_post_type`, because that’s the only way to **know** that your post type actually exists. This action is fired when a post type was registered.

Core post types are registered **twice** [for reasons](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19692). You have to wait for the **second** call, because the rewrite object is not available earlier. If your taxonomy should have permalinks, you get an error when you register it on the first call.

Affected built-in post types are:

- `post`
- `page`
- `attachment`
- `revision`
- `nav_menu_item`

Your code should be rewritten to something like this:

```
add_action( 'registered_post_type', function( $post_type ) {

    static $first_call = TRUE;

    if ( 'post' !== $post_type || $first_call ) {
        $first_call = FALSE;
        return;
    }

    register_taxonomy(
        'test',
        'post',
        [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => 'Tests',
                'singular_name' => 'Test'
            ]
        ]
    );

    $first_call = FALSE;
});
```

Comment: Hello, This is also, good, but if the custom post type is already registered what we can do ?

Comment: @dazunE Register the callback early enough.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) codex page:

> Better **be safe than sorry** when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) right after the function to interconnect them. Else you could run into minetraps where the post type isn't attached inside filter callback that run during `parse_request` or `pre_get_posts`.

So you might want to actually do it, like this:

```
// for the buil-in post type post  
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'qa_tag', 'post' );  
// for your custom post type  
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'qa_tag', 'your_cpt' );
```

Additionally there is the possibility to use the [`taxonomies`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies) argument when using [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to register your taxonomy with your custom post type, but:

> Even if you register a taxonomy while creating the post type, you must still explicitly register and define the taxonomy using [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Nonetheless it can replace above suggested [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) call.